# How to provide a custom option for an exposed filter in Views?

Tags: views

I have a site in which members can upload pictures of themselves (imagine a personals site).  Users can upload up to five pictures, and each time they upload a picture, a rule increases the value of a custom field, **Number of pictures**.

Members can search for other members using a view.  This view has a number of exposed filters.

What I would like to do is add another option, **Show members with pictures only**.  Ideally, this would be a checkbox.  However, I have no idea how to add such a thing to a view.  I could add the **Number of pictures** field as an exposed filter, but since this is an integer, users would have to type "1", which is ugly and unintuitive.  How might I start to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not able to achieve what you need with views default options.
You can create your custom views handler. In this case, it would be a filter handler.

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_filter.inc/group/views_filter_handlers/7

https://drupal.org/node/1239866

Extending views functionallity to provide an approach to your problem

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [Sexy Exposed](https://drupal.org/project/sexy_exposed) module. I think you can do it with this module, It makes any views exposed filter's select list as checkbox list.

> This module makes any views exposed filter's select list sexy using
>   the jQuery Dropdown Check List plugin.
>
> After installing this module, you will get a new checkbox on your
>   view's exposed filter settings form called 'Make it sexy'. By ticking
>   it your exposed filter will be pimped up by some hot javascript magic
>   thanks to jQuery Dropdown Check List.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a useful module, but in this case, the field is not a text value list; it's an integer value.

Comment: Sexy Exposed is not sexy UX.