# Looking for exposed filter for private file name

Tags: views

We have a view for a type of node that includes a Private File.

We cannot see a way to add an exposed filter, such as "Contains any word", and have it filter based on the file's name.

Are we missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to set that up:

1. Make sure you are not displaying teaser/full nodes. This works only for fields.
2. Under `Relationships` add your file field. You should select `Content: [field name] (field_field_name:fid)`.
3. Create new `Filter Criteria` and choose `File: Name`.
4. Choose appropriate operator and optionally expose it to the visitors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look to https://drupal.org/project/file_entity module: "This allows for additional information to be stored along with a media file such as Title, Description, Taxonomy References, Node References, Location, Date created, License information etc."

If you are not able to find a solution in this way, you can create your own filter views handler. In this case, it would be a filter handler.

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_filter.inc/group/views_filter_handlers/7

https://drupal.org/node/1239866

Extending views functionallity to provide an approach to your problem ([How to provide a custom option for an exposed filter in Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87680/how-to-provide-a-custom-option-for-an-exposed-filter-in-views/87683#87683))

Your "custom filter views handler" could get the fid of your file for each node from "field_data_field_yourfieldname.field_yourfieldname_fid" and make a join with "file_managed.fid".

In this way you can match the text introduced by the user with "file_managed.filename" database field.

Hope this helps.