# Exposed filter for file field on filename

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type with a file field.  Is there a way to create an exposed filter in a view for the filename of a document in a file field?  I can get the filename to display in the view by using a file formatter or PHP, but I can't figure out how to allow the user to filter on the document filename.  I also need the filtering to be a contains, not an equal to, so they can enter partial filenames and get results.

Comment: The way I can think of (probably way overcomplicated one) is to make a computed field that will store filename as a text - and you can do what you described with text.

Comment: Mołot, I've created a PHP field in the view to return just the filename with no extension.  That part works fine.  But I'm not seeing that field as one that is selectable for a filter.  I though I'd be able to select that field then configure it as a filter.

Comment: Are we both talking about Computed Field module?

Comment: No.  I'm just talking about using a PHP field in views.

Comment: If no one will came up with a real answer, consider taking a look on the module I pointed. There is a chance it will work for you.

Comment: This question has been answered in this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87692/looking-for-exposed-filter-for-private-file-name.