# How can I provided simplified custom exposed filter options for a field in Views?

Tags: views

On my site, users can input their nationality in a field provided by the [Countries](https://drupal.org/project/countries) module.  About half the users on my site are Japanese, and the other half come from all other countries.

I have a view that allows members to search for each other, and I want to make the nationality an exposed filter.  Since there are 200+ countries in the world, I do not want to expose the entire list of countries (this would be a selection nightmare on mobile phones).

Instead, I would like to provide a select list with three options: **All countries**, **Japan**, and **Not Japan**.

The Views UI allows administrators to select options on select lists and limit the list to the selected options by checking a box.  This is not what I want to do, because there is no way to create a **Not Japan** option (which should show all members from all countries except Japan).

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87683/5147) suggests writing a custom views filter handler, but I'm a bit confused about where to begin.

The Countries module provides its own custom handlers, but (I think) these are overkill for what I need (you have to add a relationship to the country, which allows you to filter by continent, etc.); I simply need to make a version of the basic select list handler with my three options.

It seems that most views handlers extend another.  In the `views/handlers` folder there is a file, `views_handler_filter_string.inc`, which I think I can use, but I'm not really sure what the next step is to take.

Comment: Follow-up question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89326/working-with-operators-when-manually-specifying-options-for-a-custom-views-expos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something very similar to that with the following process:

1. Implement `hook_views_api()` in a custom module

   ```
   function MYMODULE_views_api() {
     return array(
       'api' => 3,
       'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/includes/views',
     );
   }
   ```
2. Create includes/views/views_handler_filter_MYMODULE_country.inc somewhere with code similar to this (the MYMODULE bit isn't necessary, just a bit of low-tech namespacing):

   ```
   class views_handler_filter_MYMODULE_country extends views_handler_filter_in_operator {

     /**
     * Get value options for the select list.
     */
     function get_value_options() {
       // Replace $this->value_options with an appropriately filtered list.
       $this->value_options = function_to_build_filtered_list();
     }

   }
   ```
3. Register that file with the autoloader by adding this to MYMODULE.info:

   ```
   files[] = includes/views/views_handler_filter_MYMODULE_country.inc
   ```
4. Finally, implement `hook_field_views_data_alter()` to force Views to use your new handler, changing the `$field['field_name']` condition (and other similar strings based on `field_address`) to whatever makes sense for your site

   ```
   function MYMODULE_field_views_data_alter(&$result, $field, $module) {
     // Limit country exposed filters.
     if ($module == 'addressfield' && $field['field_name'] == 'field_address') {
       $result['field_data_field_address']['field_address_country']['filter']['handler'] = 'views_handler_filter_MYMODULE_country';
     }
   }
   ```